# send variables through header() php

Tags: php, web-services, http, networking, web

I'm trying to send variable through header() function from page1.php
to page2.php

this is in page1.php:

```
$id = $row['id'];                     
header("Location: index.php?vals=" . urlencode(serialize($id)));
```

and this is in page2.php

```
if($_GET['vals'])//to take the id
      {
          $id= unserialize(urldecode($_GET['vals']));
//other code
}
```

But I can't use $id in second page and get this error

> domain.tech is currently unable to handle this request. 
>   HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: What does the $id look like. You may not require the urlencode and serialize functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `urldecode()` on `$_GET['vals']`, values are automatically decoded in the `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` superglobals:

```
$id= unserialize($_GET['vals']);
```

If `$vals` is just an array of ids or something, probably better to send it through the URL as CSVs using implode / explode.